# Como procurar dentro de um repositorio SVN por alteração em um tipo de arquivo?

Tags: svn

Como eu posso fazer uma pesquisa por todas  as alterações feitas em um tipo de arquivo
(no meu caso *.js) em uma faixa de revisões.

Melhor explicado:

Eu tenho um cliente dizendo que depois de  um updade no software 
uma funcionalidade parou.

Todo o código está em um repositório SVN.
Logo entre a versão antiga e a nova, alguma coisa foi feita de forma indevida.
Eu tenho a revisão antiga e a nova ex: rev1900 ~ rev2100, 
agora o que preciso é fazer uma buscar dentro desse intervalo todos os arquivos do tipo *.js que sofreram alteração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o Tortoise SVN clique com o botão direito sobre a pasta do seu projeto e selecione a opção show log, na janela de log digite `.js`  no campo de busca em cima, selecione a opção show range do botão show em baixo e preencha o intervalo de revisões que você quer pesquisar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o TortoiseSVN que facilita bastante nestas procuras...

Basta clicar com o direito na pasta que contém seus .js e seleciona TortoiseSVN > Show Log e filtrar pela faixa de revisões.

Ele te mostrará todas as iterações por data, histórico, etc.

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)